# Executing a SQL Server stored procedure in another database server from a stored procedure without having permission to create link server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, shared-hosting, execute

I have 2 stored procedures, each of them in a separate database on a different physical server. Both these databases are created in a (separate) shared web host and consequently, I do not have server-level access. Both these servers have valid IP addresses and I've created user account with proper permission to run those stored procedure in their corresponding servers.

The question is: I want to execute one of these procedures from another and I am not able to create a linked server (because both databases are in a shared hosting environment). How can I execute the remote stored procedure from inside of the first stored procedure?

(p.s.) I checked out many questions regarding this problem but all of them had supposed that it is possible to create a linked server among these 2 servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to execute one of these procedures from another and I am not able to create a link server

Without a linked server this is not normally possible.

As [@Martin commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12987846/executing-a-sql-server-stored-procedure-in-another-database-server-from-a-stored/12987876#comment17617305_12987876), you can try [OPENDATASOURCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179856.aspx), but this is unlikely to work as it is disabled by default and is not likely to be enabled by a hosting company.

In these cases, the only option you have is to run each stored procedure separately from your application and process the results in the application.

Comment: Dear Oded: So isn't there any possibility in SQL server like opening a connection to another server in the form of connect(server, user, password) and executing the query in that context, or using a OPENQUERY and mentioning server credentials instead of mentioning the name of link server?

Comment: @Farshid - That's what linked servers are for. `OPENQUERY` requires a linked server as well. You can't do what you want without a linked server.

Comment: [`OPENDATASOURCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179856.aspx) doesn't require a linked server though may well also not be available.

Comment: @Martin - You mean the hosting company is likely to have disabled its use?

Comment: Ad Hoc Distributed Queries is disabled by default and would need to be enabled.

Comment: @Martin: Dear Martin please put your solution in answer format so that I can choose it as selected answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access details to both servers, you can create .NET CLR and deploy on the server.

Pass login, password, stored procedure name and parameters to CLR function, and in CLR code connect and execute it.

Here is an article how to return table from CLR: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131103.aspx

To connect to SQL server you will need to use generic .Net libraries: System.Data.SqlClient

Objects to use: SqlConnection, SqlCommand and SqlDataAdapter.

I have not done it myself, easier to create linked server, but I do not see why it should not work and of course you have to have rights to upload assemblies on the server.

Comment: Thanks but in my case I do not have that kind of access. But in case of having permission your answer is totally correct.